# How to make Android's FileProvider working with external storage on Android 11+

Tags: android, android-fileprovider, android-sharing

I am trying to open a file stored in the root of the external storage in another application on Android 11+.

Following the [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) docs, I write the following code:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.hmdm.fileprovidertest.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>

</application>
```

res/xml/provider_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths><external-path name="external_files" path="."/></paths>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
private static final String FILE_PATH = "/storage/emulated/0/sample.jpg";
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1000;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "FileProviderTest";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.action);
    button.setOnClickListener(view -> openFile());
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        }, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
    }
}

private void openFile() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    Uri uri;
    File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
    try {
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    } catch (/*IllegalArgument*/Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't get URI for file: " + file.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Opening Content Provider URI: " + uri.toString());
    i.setData(uri);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    try {
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to find activity for VIEW intent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The full code of the project can be found here: https://github.com/h-mdm/FileProviderTest

The problem is that when I'm trying to call the openFile() method for the existing image file, I'm getting the "Media not found" message from the system image viewer.

The logcat shows the message:

```
Failed to find provider info for com.hmdm.fileprovidertest.provider
```

The application is able to access the file (if you run the app and create the `/storage/emulated/0/sample.jpg` file, it will be displayed by the app itself).

The same code works well on Android 10 and below.

What I'm doing wrong? Are there any working examples of using FileProvider on Android 11+?

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/sample.jpg` Apps can not create files in root of external storage on Android 11+ devices to begin with. Unless they have MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE obtained. Please elaborate.

Comment: Tell the value of file.getAbsolutePath(). You are very messing around with that path. Confusing. Dont start with a file:// uri. Dont define a macro if you come for help. Makes code difficult to read. Dont assign uri twice.

Comment: Using FileProvider has not changed.

Comment: `problem is that when I'm trying to call the openFile() method` Sorry but where are you doing that?

Comment: The app doesn't create a file in the root of the external storage, the file `/storage/emulated/0/sample.jpg` is assumed to exist. I adjusted the MainActivity code as per your comment.  The file.getAbsolutePath() is `/storage/emulated/0/sample.jpg`.

Comment: If the file is not created by your app it has no access on Android 11+. Try with file.exists() and file.canRead() before trying to get an uri of file provider and launching the intent.

Comment: The app requests `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions. The file is accessible, and it can be read by the app. You can refer to the github link for the full code where the app reads the file and displays it in the ImageView. But FileProvider still doesn't work.

Comment: The file is accessible by the app. File.exists() returns true. File.canRead() returns true.

Comment: Sorry, i do not believe that your app can read that file if it does not belong to your app. Only with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)` That statement overwrites the addFlags() statement and hence the read permission you gave. Swap those statements. addFlags() should be last.

Comment: `i.setData(uri);` You should use i.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");

Comment: `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)` That statement overwrites the addFlags() statement - that's the correct answer, thank you! Please convert it as an answer so I could mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

That statement overwrites the addFlags() statement and hence the read permission you gave.

Swap those statements. As addFlags() should be last.